# Creating a Drupal form export query

Tags: sql, database, drupal, drupal-7, export-to-excel

I have the task of creating an export query to dump our drupal website form fields into an excel file. Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to perform this task? tutorial links or samples? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export_webforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this module :
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export

You just have to create a view, select your fields and choose the export type (csv,xls,...)

Howto here : https://www.drupal.org/node/1820452

Comment: Thank you! Any solution to have the csv file download rather than open up in a new tab on the browser?